# "send as" an existing Mail Contact in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a client who needs multiple users to "send as" an existing Mail Contact under Exchange 2010.  Is this possible?

I understand how to grant "send as" permissions on a mailbox, but not for a Mail Contact.

Please help?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because you don't own that email domain.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the mail contact isn't for an address within the domain they own?

Comment: Ok, maybe a bit of a stretch, but a mail contact is generally an external address outside of the domains for which your exchange install is authoritative. Glad to update if I'm having a brain fart on this one.

Comment: @Zoredache  Because if it was for a user or address within their domain it would be trivial to send as that user?

Answer (score 3):

They can add the send-as permission by editing the contact object via adsiedit or powershell. They need to add the Distinguished name (from the user that needs send-as) to the PublicDelegates attribute of the mail-enabled contact. I would not set this for an e-mail domain that you do not own, as this is a good way to be blacklisted. In my case, I own a different mail domain for SharePoint and users want to send-as the SharePoint site so the return mail is saved on SharePoint.